# Plotly plot axis line thickness not behaving [Python]

Tags: python, plotly

When I try to increase the x-axis thickness, plotly overlays a new axis line (of the desired thickness), instead of just increasing the thickness of the existing axis line. Am I doing something wrong? For example if I edit the layout property ‘xaxis’:{‘linewidth’:3}, it produces a new line under the xaxis (above the xlabels) which has width of 3, but it looks bad obviously. What can I do about this? I’ve tried by editing ‘zerolinewidth’:3 as well but this does nothing.

Here's an example code with the issue reproduced - if we remove the xaxis property 'linewdith':3 in the layout dict then the plot is default. I just want control over the axis linewidth.

```
# Example axis problem
import plotly.offline as pyo
from plotly.graph_objs import *
from plotly import tools
import plotly.plotly as py
pyo.offline.init_notebook_mode()

xdata = list(range(6))
ydata = [0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1]

trace1 = {'type':'scatter',
     'x':xdata,
     'y':ydata,
     'mode':'markers+lines'}

layout = {'title':'some plot',
     'xaxis':{'title':'x-axis',
             'linewidth':3},
     'yaxis':{'title':'y-axis'}}

data = Data([trace1])

fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

pyo.iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`linewidth` specifies the line width of the frame around the graph, see here for an [example.](https://plot.ly/python/axes/#styling-and-coloring-axes-and-the-zeroline)

You are probably looking for [`zerolinewidth`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-zerolinewidth).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I had tried it before and it did nothing - not sure why but it's working now.